# p4v not looking in correct root directory for workspace

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am trying to look up history for a workspace in p4v. I believe I changed the root directory at one point, and the updated root is shown in the workspace info from p4v and from command line. However, I get the following when I attempt to review history.

> ```
> Path 'c:\path_to_old_root\...' is not under client's root 'c:\path_to_new_root'.
> ```

The Perforce command run is:

> p4 changes -s submitted -l -m 100 c:\path_to_old_root...

Additionally, when looking at the workspace in the selectro on the left side pane it shows `c:\path_to_old_root\` for the local directory.

I am unsure why it is the generating the command/determining local directory to use in the manner it is.

Comment: Do you happen to have a spec depot? If so, you could find the worksapce under //spec/client/... It will display the history (just like depot'ed) files.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why this occurred, but it appears files in the .p4qt directory were not correctly updated. [Based on the suggestion that deleting said directory might be helpful](http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/3466-wrong-path-in-workspace-tree/), I searched the directory for occurrences of the old root path and replaced them with the new root path. This appears to have corrected the problem.

Comment: You are more patient than me. I deleted the directory, skipped the "wizard", and was in my moved workspace in seconds. Thanks, though.